# how to find the data values from sql table using c# without writing any sql command?

Tags: c#-3.0

at Value Labs the interviewer had asked me such kind of question. 
C# .Net Question

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select empno,ename from employee where empid='101'");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but here we don't want to to use Query of command to take the values is this possible?

Comment: Somewhere, somebody must have written some form of SQL to communicate with the database. You can put layers upon layers of cool ORM between it, but in the end... somebody wrote SQL.

Comment: Reading your post again, maybe I misunderstood. Can you be a bit more precise about the question. What exactly was the question?

Comment: the question is how to find empno , ename from employrr table using c# without an query...

Comment: You cannot. Simple as that. A query is the interface to the database. Short of hacking the databases data files, there is no way.